# Delete duplicate keys with relation algebra without count

Tags: relational-theory, relations, relational-algebra

Hi I am new to relational algebra. I was wondering if there is a way to remove the tuples from a table using relational algebra that have the same **Value**  occurring in multiple columns or same column multiple times (This comparison is **only** done on the Value1 and Value2 columns and **not** on Key1 or Key2 columns ).

e.g. I want to keep only [4, 401,4,501] and [6, 701,6,801] but remove everything else. But I want to achieve this without using count.

```
Key1   | Value1 |Key2   | Value2    
-------|--------|-------|-------
 1     | 101    |  1    | 101
 2     | 101    |  2    | 201
 3     | 101    |  3    | 301
 4     | 401    |  4    | 501
 5     | 201    |  5    | 901
 6     | 701    |  6    | 801
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why is key1=5 not kept?

Comment: Key1 = 5 is not kept because value1=201 (for key1=5) appears for key2=2 where value2=201. I want avoid duplication values even if it is in another column.

Comment: The problem is not clearly specified. “Remove the tuples from a table using relational algebra that have the same value occurring in multiple columns or same column multiple times.” 4 is present in multiple columns in the same row so it should be removed too, according to the specificiation.

Comment: My bad. I want to remove the tuples based on values and not the key. In this case 4 is a key.